is independent claim 2 acceptable
could I use below 2 independent claims in a patent?

The apparatus comprise A, B, C:
The apparatus might further comprise D, wherein whether D is needed or not depending on the function of the apparatus..

Is this claim 2 acceptable, pls teach me if you could. have a great day.

Is there some reason you can't just write "2. The apparatus of Claim 1, further comprising D whereby [recite the benefit that adding D accomplishes]"? The whereby is optional but it indicates to the reader why one would want to add D.

Hi, @bhuff36, I hope you are well, the drawing include D, and furthermore, most of the product should be with D, but some occasion, D is not essential.----my purpose is to broad the protection, and I am OK with D but if possible, I'd like to remove D from independent claim 1,  thanks.

If it works without D, and you feel you have a chance to clear the prior art without D, then by all means write the main independent claim without D.

Note that you didn't specify whether you are writing original claims or you are presenting amended claims. It may not be proper to newly present a claim without D if it was previously described as essential.

It is vague and the conditional is not needed and is confusing. “Might” is inherent in a dependent claim.
You do not need to define the benefit of D, just claim 1 further comprising D.
